# Concatenating datas from different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I have an Excel workbook with 2 sheets. Sheet #1 contains 2 columns, names and points.

```
| A         | B  |
|-----------|----|
| John Doe  | 65 |
| Jolly Doe | 45 |
| Hello Doe | 50 |
```

Sheet #2 contains just one column, names.

```
| A         |
|-----------|
| John Doe  |
| Hello Doe |
```

I want to get points of every name which in sheet #2. So result should be like this:

```
| A         | B  |
|-----------|----|
| John Doe  | 65 |
| Hello Doe | 50 |
```

Using this formula on Sheet 2 to get points but getting **John Doe** now point of John's

```
=VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet1!A1:A10;1)
```

Can you show me a way to achieve this?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` is the function you want. Info here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: I'm using VLOOKUP with FIND() but it's getting wrong cell values. I'll share my formula in a minute

Comment: @Excellll , just shared my formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close with your formula.

Use:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$99999,2,FALSE)
```

Your reference to `Sheet2!B1:B999` should be `Sheet1!$A$2:$B$99999`.  Your original is actually pointing to the place where you want to put the results, not the source of the numbers.

The Vlookup() function needs:

What you are looking for - A2

Where you want to look - Sheet1!$A2:$B99999  (your look up table)

What you want to return - 2 (the second column of your table)

If you want a close but not exact match - False

By putting the $ in the range $A$2:$B$99999, the reference to the table will be fixed.  So when you copy the formula down through the rest of the cells, the look up table range will not change.

Comment: What do you mean by 'close but not exact match' ?

Comment: @Eray If you use false, it will return the correct value, and if you use true (assuming that your data in column 1 of the lookup range is ordered) it will choose the closest value